# Is there a way to auto set alt tags on images in PDFs with Acrobat Pro?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, accessibility

We're creating pdfs of images in acrobat pro using create pdf ->combine files.

The files we are using are all large file images that have been fully marked up in adobe bridge. We need these PDFs to be fully accessible. Is there a way that we can set the alt tag to automatically be set to a give meta tag attached to one of the images?

Comment: There are no tags in Acrobat. Only bookmarks, hyperlinks and comments. Are you trying to make a contact sheet? That's done in bridge + Photoshop

Comment: There are alt tags for images in acrobat. It's part of making PDFs accessible and compliant with WCAG standards. They even show up if you run a full accessibility scan in acrobat pro.

Comment: Indeed there are alt tags but GUI support for them is quite limited.